# PHP / Mysql / Highscore table - How to check existing scores and replace them

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-update

I have a simple game with a highscore system. The user can write his name and his score will be saved in the highscore table. The problem is: When a user plays several time with the same name there's always a new entry into the database. How can I change my code that there will be only one entry per name. How can I check the usernames existing score and only update the score when it's better? How to do this in my code? Thanks in advance

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

require 'config.php';

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

if(isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['score'])) {

 //Lightly sanitize the GET's to prevent SQL injections and possible XSS attacks
 $name = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']));
 $score = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['score']));
 $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$tbl_name` (`id`,`name`,`score`) VALUES ('','$name','$score');");

 if($sql){

      //The query returned true - now do whatever you like here.
      echo 'Your score was saved. Congrats!';

 }else{

      //The query returned false - you might want to put some sort of error reporting here. Even logging the error to a text file is fine.
      echo 'There was a problem saving your score. Please try again later.'.mysql_error();;

 }

}else{
 echo 'Your name or score wasnt passed in the request. Make sure you add ?name=NAME_HERE&score=1337 to the tags.';
}

mysql_close($dblink);//Close off the MySQL connection to save resources.
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if(isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['score'])) {
    $name = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']));
    $score = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['score']));

    $checkExist = mysql_query("SELECT `name`, `score` FROM `$tbl_name` WHERE `name` = '$name'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($checkExist);

    if (mysql_num_rows($checkExist) > 0){
        if ($score > $row['score']){
            $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `$tbl_name` SET `score` = '$score' WHERE `name` = '$name'");
        } else {
            // ERROR MSG: Your new score is lower.(not updating the database)
        }
    } else {
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$tbl_name` (`id`,`name`,`score`) VALUES ('','$name','$score');");
    }

 if ($sql){
      //The query returned true - now do whatever you like here.
      echo 'Your score was saved. Congrats!';
 } else {    
      //The query returned false - you might want to put some sort of error reporting here. Even logging the error to a text file is fine.
      echo 'There was a problem saving your score. Please try again later.'.mysql_error();;

 }
```

Comment: Does this check existing scores and only update when the new score is better?

Comment: Ops, sorry i forget to check the score. Wait a minute.

Comment: Well, you can test it now.

Comment: Cool, thank you. Do you know how to write the "Name" in uppercase into the database?

Comment: Goop, you need to refer to people by their at-name to let them know they have a reply. I don't think @hansistr got your message, since he/she re-asked the same as a question.

Comment: Sorry, I am new here, but will use it in future. Thank you, @halder!

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

make your name column as unique:

```
CREATE TABLE highscore (
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    score INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
    PRIMARY KEY (username, id)
);
```

if user exists, then check is score higher as the stored. it is then make update with new highscore.

```
INSERT INTO 
    `$tbl_name`
SET
    `name` = '$name',
    `score` = '$score'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `score` = IF (VALUES(`score`) > `score`, VALUES(`score`), `score`) ;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/insert-on-duplicate.html